# Can Marketing Cloud tell me if a phone number added is Mobile or Landline

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to know if the US mobile number received is landline or Mobile ?

Comment: Seems unlikely to be possible on any technology stack, and is not really related to Salesforce.

Comment: You should look into how you are opting in phone numbers. JOIN keywords obviously come from mobile numbers. Other sources should have an opt-in to SMS and thus your audience will knowingly put in a mobile number

Answer (score 1):

The marketing cloud does not have a verification feature to check mobile vs landline. However it will mark a number [held after 2 failed messages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_bounced_messages_and_held_numbers.htm&type=5) within 30 days:

There are 3rd party tools you can use to validate numbers which you can find through a google search.

Depending how you are collecting the mobile numbers you should have a low amount of landline numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way through Marketing Cloud.